# Integrate MongoDB with Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I currently have a project which is using MySQL. However, I also have some data in a `Mongo` database that I need to fetch. I know there is a python library called `Django`, but I think it's changing the backend database to MongoDB. I wonder if there is any way I can fetch data from the MongoDB while the rest of the project is still using `MySQL`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. You should be running the mongo server in the backend.
You can access it in the views as,

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

server="localhost"
port = 27017
#Establish a connection with mongo instance.
conn = MongoClient(server,port)
```

After connecting using the above code, you can normally use mongo commands to make CRUD applications on mongodb data.
For example,

```
polls = conn.db_name.collection_name.find({})
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I add all these in views.py?

Comment: And do I need to change the database setting in settings.py?

Comment: Yes you can use it in view.py and no need to change anything in settings.py.

Comment: I just checked pymongo documentations, are we supposed to use MongoClient instead of Connection now?

Comment: Sorry for that Connection was for according to older version, yes you should use MongoClient for the newer version. (Also, updating the answer)